# Tkinter Combobox accepting array as values

Tags: python, list, tkinter, combobox

I am using a Combobox within a Tkinter GUI. The set-up is as follows:

```
list = np.arange(10)
var = IntVar(value=list[0])
box = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=var, value=list)
```

It works as expected; but there is only one problem - for the first and last values of the drop-down list, the square brackets are attached to the integer.

You can see this from:

```
box['values']
```

The output for this is:

```
('[0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9]')
```

You can see why the problem appears, check the first and last string characters within box['values'].

I need to remove this, since I am using the combobox value directly as the index location of another array. Therefore, it gives an error when the first/last element of the list are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert you numpy array to a list by `tolist()`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np

root = tk.Tk()
list = np.arange(10).tolist()

box = ttk.Combobox(root, value=list)
box.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I did not create a new list, but used the tolist() command within the ComboBox, because I wanted the variable list to be an integer array (easier to do a search later on).